# "Z" Variable is undefined when used to represent a matrix for sigmoid function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, octave, sigmoid

I'm a high school student and I just started going into machine learning to further my knowledge of coding. I tried out the program Octave and been working with neurological networks, or at least, tried to. In my first program, however, I already found myself at an impasse with my Sigmoid gradient function. When I try to make the function work for each value within a matrix, I have no idea how to do so. I tried placing z as the parameter of the function but it says that "z" itself is undefined. I have no knowledge on C or C++, and I'm still an amateur in this area, so sorry if I take some time to understand. Thanks to anyone who offers to help!

I'm running Octave 4.4.1, and I haven't tried any other solution yet, as I don't really have any.

```
% Main Code
    g = sigGrad([-2 -1 0 1 2]);
% G is supposed to be my sigmoid Gradient for each value of Theta, which is the matrix within it's parameters.
```

```
% Sigmoid Gradient function
    function g = sigGrad(z)
    g = zeros(size(z));
% This is where the code tells me that z is undefined
    g = sigmoid(z).*(1.-sigmoid(z));
% I began by initializing a matrix of zeroes with the size of z
% It should later do the Gradient Equation, but it marks z as undefined before that
```

```
% Sigmoid function
    g = sigmoid(z)
    g = 1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z));
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Functions and Scripts](https://octave.org/doc/v5.1.0/Functions-and-Scripts.html#Functions-and-Scripts) section of the Octave help to understand their differences and functioning. Try to properly implement your `sigGrad` function at first.

Comment: Can you share your sigGrad() function?

Comment: Updated Gradient Function code to show it's correct name (sigGrad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, I make out that you are committing simple syntax mistakes, I'd recommend get a gist of octave  first than diving into the code head on. That being said you have to declare your functions with proper syntax and use them as shown below:

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
%   SIGMOID Compute sigmoid function
%   J = SIGMOID(z) computes the sigmoid of z.

g = 1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z));
end
```

And the other piece of code should be

```
function g = sigGrad(z)
%   sigGrad returns the gradient of the sigmoid function evaluated at z
%   g = sigGrad(z) computes the gradient of the sigmoid function evaluated at z. 
%   This should work regardless if z is a matrix or a vector.
%   In particular, if z is a vector or matrix, you should return the gradient for each element.

g = zeros(size(z));

g = sigmoid(z).*(1 - sigmoid(z));

end
```

And then finally call the above implemented functions using:

```
g = sigGrad([1 -0.5 0 0.5 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like it was my Syntax after all, will try to learn more of octave before coding right away!

Comment: Don't forget to up-vote and approve if an answer helps you. Cheers :)